# Ember wrapping issues getting data directly from the component

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use data from a component but the yield is not coming through. Its almost like its not hitting the component template?

Is there anything wrong with the structure of this code

page

```
{{#wrapping-component
  as |fullName|
}}
  {{fullName}}
  {{log fullName}}
{{/wrapping-component}}
```

..
wrapping-component.hbs

```
<div class="wrapper-component">
  {{yield fullName}}
</div>
```

wrapping-component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var WrappingComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  fullName: function(){
    console.log("get blue");
    return "blue";
  },

});

export default WrappingComponent;
```

so on the page I should see "blue" appear - but its not showing anything

Comment: I had spelt the component and the js for the component differently

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may want a property instead of a function?

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({

  fullName: "blue",

  // if you want a computed property:
  fullName2: computed(function() {
    return 'blue';
  });


});
```

that will print blue in your template.
otherwise the `fullName` reference is an uninvoked function